# jQuery target element within parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have structure like this

```
<div id="mali_oglasi">
    <p class="mali_oglas">
        <span class="name">Predaja7</span>
        <span class="body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec urna eros, viverra nec porta vitae, luctus at ipsum. Pellentesque porta imperdiet purus, at pellentesque nisl lacinia et. Nam id justo do</span>
        <span class="contact_author">Saša</span>
        <span class="date_created">2012-03-13 14:36:30</span>
        <span class="date_expires">2012-04-12 14:36:30</span>
        <span class="email">imalimalomrk@gmail.com</span>

        <span>Pirot</span>

        <span>Auto i Moto</span>
                                                                                                   <a class="obrisi" id="16">Obrisi</a>
        <a class="izmeni" id="16">Izmeni</a>
    </p>
    <p class="mali_oglas">
        <span class="name">Predaja6</span>

        <span class="body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec urna eros, viverra nec porta vitae, luctus at ipsum. Pellentesque porta imperdiet purus, at pellentesque nisl lacinia et. Nam id justo do</span>
        <span class="contact_author">Saša</span>
        <span class="date_created">2012-03-13 14:36:19</span>
        <span class="date_expires">2012-04-12 14:36:19</span>
        <span class="email">imalimalomrk@gmail.com</span>
        <span>Pirot</span>

        <span>Auto i Moto</span>
                                                                                                   <a class="obrisi" id="15">Obrisi</a>
        <a class="izmeni" id="15">Izmeni</a>
    </p>.....           
</div>
```

and JS:

```
$('.izmeni').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.name').replaceWith('<input />');
});
```

I want to target span with class .name in the parent but nothing is happening???

Comment: id attributes should not start with numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use `closest` to start beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

Using `siblings` targets your elements sisters and brother (other DOM elements with the same parent):

```
$('.izmeni').on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.name').replaceWith('<input />');
});
```

Note: im not sure your using the `on()` method in the correct manner ... the `on()` method should be a attached to a parent element of objects that are added after the DOM has loaded, like this :

```
$(parent).on('click', '.izmeni', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.name').replaceWith('<input />');
});
```

where `parent` is a parent of the actual element you are listening on, in your case `mali_oglasi` could be the parent if the `a` are to be added within that `div`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.izmeni').on('click', function(e) {
    $(e.target).closest('.SomeParent').find('.elementToReplace').replaceWith('<input />');
});
```

Comment: Notice the `e` and `closest-find` combination.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like from your structure `.izmeni` is a sibling of `.name`

Take a look at jQuery siblings http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

```
$('.izmeni').on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.name').replaceWith('<input />');
});
```